# Could it be ADHD?

Tags: behavior, adhd

My sister has shifted to our city recently after losing her husband in an accident. We were not that close earlier. Last time when we met her kid was about 8 years old and going to school and all was well.

Now he has grown up and is around 20 years of age. He does not behave properly. He does not give respect to elders. He was poor in studies and dropped out of school before finishing high school. He does not like to be corrected. I believe this could be the reason for dropping out of school. He does what he thinks is right. Recently his aggression has increased and is out of control and resorts to thrashing his mother as well. When he was young he was not hanging out with any of his mates. As of now he just eats and sleeps.

I cannot answer for why this was not corrected in earlier stages. I am looking for answers on what could be done to correct at this stage. Or is it too late? Just hate the fact that she has to cope up with this kid all alone.

Comment: Possibility 1: Kid lost his dad. 
Possibility 2: Drugs.
Possibility 3: Both. Possibility 4: Something else.

Comment: It *could* be anything. Or likely a combination of things. It's never too late to get help, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely it is ADHD, but the only one to diagnose that is a trained therapist (which I am not).  It is extremely rare that ADHD is diagnosed first in adults, but it does happen (as it did with me, for example.)  ADHD, however, isn't the only mental "illness" out there, as I am sure you know.

Therapy is unlikely to hurt, so why not try it?  Something is clearly awry, so getting outside help is the best thing I can recommend.

Comment: I thought that there could have been ADHD symptoms from childhood itself but nothing was done to stop it. We are seeking medical advice, just wanted a hint of what could have gone wrong :( Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You might also try to see a psychiatrist -- trauma induced Major Depressive Disorder can be helped by medication as well. Be very wary of ADHD medication -- it will make the behavior worse of the diagnosis is wrong.